# File Transfer Failed : From RaspberryPi3 to My Mobile on Bluetooth

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, data-transfer, file

File Transfer Failed : From RaspberryPi3 to My Mobile on Bluetooth

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and the following command complete.

$ sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth
$ sudo apt-get install bluetooth blueman bluez

and I completed pairing my raspberry and mobile (or PC-window7).

infact, bluetooth speaker very well doing on raspberry pi 3.

AND i am success that :

photo file in my raspberry Pi --> my mobile (or PC-window7)

BUT i am failed that :

photo file in my mobile (or PC) -----> my raspberry Pi

I dont'n know the reason.